# getting response 404 and app crash retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am trying to implement retrofit for get and store advertise related int value in my android application. I am getting response like `{"banner_on":"1","int_on":"1","int_click":"3"}`from API.

I am using code in splash screen like this

```
Retrofit retrofit = ApiClient.getClient();
            ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
            apiService.getads().enqueue(new Callback<Ads>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Ads> call, Response<Ads> response) {

                        constant.banner_on = response.body().banner_on();
                        constant.int_on = response.body().int_on();
                        constant.int_click = response.body().int_click();

                }

                 @Override
                 public void onFailure(Call<Ads> call, Throwable t) {

                 }
            });
```

My Ads Model is like below

```
public final class Ads {
    @SerializedName("success")

    private int banner_on;
    private int int_on;
    private int int_click;

    public int banner_on() {
        return banner_on;
    }
    public int int_on() {
        return int_on;
    }
    public int int_click() {
        return int_click;
    }
}
```

and my ApiService is like below

```
 @GET("getads.php")
    Call<Ads>getads();
```

I am getting error like below

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.myapp.example.model.Ads.banner_on()' on a null object reference
```

Let me know if someone can correct me where I am wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response.body() will be null if the request is unsuccessful.

```
if(response.isSuccessful()) //use response.body();
else // use response.errorBody();
```

Comment: @Priya That should be a typo, use isSuccessful